# Return any number of matching groups with re findall in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a relatively complex string that contains a bunch of data. I am trying to extract the relevant pieces of the string using a regex command. The portions I am interested in are contained in square brackets, like this:

```
s = '"data":["value":3.44}] lol haha "data":["value":55.34}] 
                "data":["value":2.44}] lol haha "data":["value":56.34}]'
```

And the regex expression I have built is as follows:

```
l = re.findall(r'\"data\"\:.*(\[.*\])', s)
```

I was expecting this to return

```
['["value":3.44}]', '["value":55.34}]', '["value":2.44}]', '["value":56.34}]']
```

But instead all I get is the last one, i.e.,

```
['["value":56.34}]']
```

How can I catch 'em all?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a regular expression to parse JSON?

Comment: @Barmar Mostly because the data I have to work with is embedded in JSON. Is there a better way??

Comment: Yes, use a json parser... ;)

Comment: Actually, that `lol haha` stuff makes it invalid JSON.

Comment: `.*` is greedy.  It will grab as many elements as it can.  You can make it lazy by adding a question mark `.*?`.  Also, you don't need to escape the colon.

Comment: Yes, the `lol haha` stuff is me adding filler to a considerably less complex string in order to emulate the actual data I am working with.

Comment: Is the actual data valid JSON? If so, you should use a JSON parser rather than regexp.

Comment: It is, and that sounds like far less work. I was unaware of their existence, but it makes sense that they're around considering how much JSON there is out there, so I probably ought to have checked it out first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because quantifiers are greedy by default. So `.*` will match everything between the first `"data":` and the last `[`, so there's only one `[...]` left to match.

Use non-greedy quantifiers by adding `?`.

```
l = re.findall(r'\"data\"\:.*?(\[.*?\])', s)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly right. Thanks a bunch, that's a really basic solution that I am surprised I missed!

Comment: Greedy vs. non-greedy matching is one of the more difficult concepts to incorporate into regex thnking, so it isn't surprising you overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) to extract the relevant content iteratively:

```
import re

s = '"data":["value":3.44}] lol haha "data":["value":55.34}] "data":["value":2.44}] lol haha "data":["value":56.34}]'
for m in re.finditer(r'(\[.*?\])', s):
    print m.group(1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["value":3.44}]
["value":55.34}]
["value":2.44}]
["value":56.34}]
```